# Input Alert Auto-Capitalization for Words?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, capitalization

I have found that for UITextFields I can use

```
UITextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
```

to make the contents autocapitalization for words.  Is there a way to take the text from an input alert and also do the same thing with making the first letter of each word a capital letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString has a property

```
capitalizedString
```

which will make all the words capital in a string, so take the text and apply this property to your string, this will make all the words capital.

Comment: take the text of input alert in a string, then yourString. capitalizedString() will return your expected string.

Comment: Worked well. I appreciate.